tsc not found in Docker using AWS App Runner
So I have searched everywhere over the past 3 days to figure out why my apprunner.yaml file for AWS App Runner is erroring with tsc: command not found
I am attempting to run 2 commands to compile my Typescript code into Javascript to run. This is tsc and tsc-alias
Here is my package.json with my commands.

As you can see below I have typescript as a dependency as suggested.

Attempt 1.
I have tried calling npm install to install all dependencies (including typescript) and then calling tsc and tsc-alias which AWS App Runner errored and produced the below logs:

Attempt 2.
So then I seen people mentioning that tsc and tsc-alias have to be globally installed so changed the apprunner.yaml to look like the following.

The above produced the exact same error tsc: command not found.
When I try and run this locally in my Dockerfile it builds fine, so I am wondering is there something I am missing?

do you have typescript installed as dev dependency?

@antokhio Nope, I just have it in my dependencies so that npm install downloads it

Install globally and run with npx tsc

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shots with actual text?
